# Login button in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is it possible to load the Facebook log in button onto a preference activity?

How can I set a preference layout?

Answer (score -1):

Referring to [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3)

> Add the button to your layout XML file with the full class name, com.facebook.widget.LoginButton:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Comment: this is not what I was looking for. I'm looking for a way to integrate LoginButton in a Preference and not a layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450430/how-can-i-integrate-facebook-loginbutton-in-preferencescreen